# Index of first child on a list is lost when sending it to the parent with React.CloneElement (React + Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a custom Dropdown component and I'm having trouble using `children`.

The Dropdown component has 3 levels, and the children are the options which are passed from the grandparent `Dropdown` component to the grandchild `Option` component like so:

```ts
// GRANDPARENT
const sampleOptions = [{value: 'Option 1'}, {value: 'Option 2'}, {value: 'Option 3'}]

return (
  <Dropdown>
    {sampleOptions.map((option) => (
      <Option key={value}>{value}</Option>
    ))}
  </Dropdown>
)
```

The `Option` component is as follows:

```ts
// CHILD
const handleSelect = () => {
  onSelect && optionIndex && onSelect(optionIndex);
  // console.log(optionIndex) returns the correct index
}

return (
  <Option onClick={handleSelect} selected={selected}>
    // content
  </Option>
)
```

**The problem** occurs in the middle parent component called `OptionGroup`, where **the index of the first child is not passed to the parent at all**:

```ts
// PARENT
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(defaultOption)
  
const options = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    onSelect: (i) => {
      // console.log(i) does not work on the first child only!
      const newIndex = Number(i)
      setActiveIndex(newIndex)
    },
    selected: index === activeIndex,
    optionIndex: index,
  })
})

return (
  <OptionGroup>
    {options}
  </OptionGroup>
)
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is here: `onSelect && optionIndex && onSelect(optionIndex);`. You're only executing onSelect if onSelect and optionIndex is truthy. But optionIndex is not truthy for 0 (0 == false). Replace it with `onSelect && onSelect(optionIndex);`

Comment: Or just use `optionIndex !== null`. Well spotted! @UgurEren

Comment: Also, yeah, @ChrisG is kinda right, you can check if it is not undefined

Comment: @ChrisG `OptionGroup` is the parent, but the children are sent from a grandparent. I'm going to edit the question to be clearer about it.

Comment: That's ok, Ugur has already spotted what's causing the issue.

Comment: @UgurEren and Chris you are so right. That was the problem. I hadn't thought about 0 not being truthy. Thank you for saving me some white hairs!